# Type of structure for saving private chat log in Redis

Tags: redis

I am writing chat program and I want to do history of chats so I need to store some values. First is post data like:

```
socket.on('send private',function(data){
      var d = new Date();
      var doc1 = { 'name': 'message id ' + d.getTime(),  'user_from': data.userfrom,  'user_to': data.userto, 'message': data.message };    
      client.hmset('messages:' + d.getTime(), doc1, function(err, replies) {
      });
 });
```

But when i get data from history, i don't know how do to sort data by date and by user_from  + user_to. I want to make chat private between two user.

I am not sure if its is possible using redis - i am new to this nosql database concept. I think i shoud use hashes in some way but have no idea how.

Thank for read, sorry my english not good.

Answer (score 0):

With Redis you will need to manage your own indexes. It's common for people to use the keys with a standard delimiter to do this.

for example, try messages:message_id or messages:user_id_message_id and have a incr key to track your current index. This works well as Redis has atomic writes. It's totally doable but you may want to store history in an alternate datastore as Redis is more commonly seen as a non-persistent cache and chances are you will lose some historical data at some point.

Comment: thank for help
can you help me how to sort data by date

Comment: if you sort by key you will inherently be sorting by date. If you have a date field as a key in a set I think you can do something like: sort myset by date:*